# PHP combine array based on value of particular element

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [count] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [count] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 513
            [count] => 0
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
             [id] => 561
             [count] => 1
         )
     [4] => Array
         (
              [id] => 613
              [count] => 7
         )

)
```

What I want to do is create a new array, that totals the count where the id values are the same.  So for example, the new array would look like this:

```
Array ( 

[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 123
            [count] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 513
            [count] => 0
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
             [id] => 561
             [count] => 1
         )
     [3] => Array
         (
              [id] => 613
              [count] => 7
         )

)
```

Would anyone know a good method to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Just iterating through and creating a new array if the id is same as the previous id (saved) and adding the count, but I feel like there must be a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and simple:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($data_array as $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($value['id'], $new_array)) {
        $new_array[$value['id']] += $value['count'];
    } else {
        $new_array[$value['id']] = $value['count'];
    }
}

echo print_r($new_array,true);
```

I made it `id => value` since there didn't seem to need another array for data when the `id` could be used as the array's key.

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not making an associative array of `id => count`

Comment: Well, there's more values in the actual array

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the following function (I didn't tested the code, but it should work ):

```
function get_count_array($arr) {
    $new_array = array(); 

    foreach($arr as $item) {
        $found = false;

        //loop through all the current new items to check if we already have it
        for($i = 0; $i < count($new_array); $i++) {
            //do we have it?
            if($new_array[$i]['id'] == $item['id']) { 
                $new_array[$i]['count'] += 1;
                $found = true;

                break;
            }
        }

        if(!$found) {
            $new_array[] = array('id' => $item['id'], 'count' => 0);
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```